# How to convert byte[] into MemcacheServicePb$Memcache*Request in ApiProxy.Delegate.makeSyncCall?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deserialization

I am implementing the [com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.Delegate interface](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy.Delegate) in order to proxy memcache API calls on my GAE/J apps. My proxy code is executed i.e. I am intercepting the memcache API calls.

```
public class CustomDelegate implements Delegate {
    // ...
    public byte[] makeSyncCall(
        Environment environment,
        String packageName,
        String methodName,
        byte[] request) throws ApiProxyException
    {
        return this.baseDelegate.makeSyncCall(environment, packageName, methodName, request);         
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now I would like to inspect the memcache get/set/increment requests themselves. Deserializing the **byte[] request** parameter of **makeSyncCall()** into a instances of

- com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb$MemcacheSetRequest
- com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb$MemcacheGetRequest
- com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb$MemcacheIncrementRequest

would allow me to
* detect hot keys
* keep track of item sizes

How I transfer **byte[] request** into Memcache*Request instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of some code that deserializes the requests and responses

```
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb.MemcacheGetRequest;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb.MemcacheGetResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb.MemcacheIncrementRequest;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb.MemcacheIncrementResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb.MemcacheSetRequest;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServicePb.MemcacheSetResponse;
...

  private static void examineRequest(String pkg, String method, byte[] request) {
    try {
      if (pkg.equals("memcache")) {
        if (method.equals("Get")) {
          MemcacheGetRequest req = MemcacheGetRequest.parseFrom(request);
          for (Iterable<Byte> key : req.getKeyList()) {
            ... key ...
          }
        } else if (method.equals("Set")) {
          MemcacheSetRequest req = MemcacheSetRequest.parseFrom(request);
          for (MemcacheSetRequest.Item item : req.getItemList()) {
            ... item.getKey() ... item.getValue() ...
          }
        } else if (method.equals("Increment")) {
          MemcacheIncrementRequest req = MemcacheIncrementRequest.parseFrom(request);
          ... req.getKey()... req.getDelta()... req.getInitialValue() ... 
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      ... 
    }
  }

  private static void examineResponse(String pkg, String method, byte[] response) {
    try {
      if (pkg.equals("memcache")) {
        if (method.equals("Get")) {
          MemcacheGetResponse resp = MemcacheGetResponse.parseFrom(response);
          for (MemcacheGetResponse.Item item : resp.getItemList()) {
            ... item.getKey() ... item.getValue() ...
          });

        } else if (method.equals("Set")) {
          MemcacheSetResponse resp = MemcacheSetResponse.parseFrom(response);
          ... resp.getSetStatusList() ... 

        } else if (method.equals("Increment")) {
          MemcacheIncrementResponse resp = MemcacheIncrementResponse.parseFrom(response);
          ... resp.getNewValue() ... 

        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      ... 
    }

  }
```

Calling the above from the `makeSyncCall` is straightforward, but calling from the the `makeAsyncCall` method is a bit tricky, because you want to defer examining the response until after the Future completes.  One way to do this is to wrap the Future, as shown below

```
public class ApiProxyHook<E extends Environment> implements Delegate<E> {
  private Delegate<E> baseDelegate;
  ... 

  @Override
  public byte[] makeSyncCall(E environment, String pkg, String method, byte[] request)
      throws ApiProxy.ApiProxyException {
    byte[] response = this.baseDelegate.makeSyncCall(environment, pkg, method, request);

    examineRequest(pkg, method, request);
    examineResponse(pkg, method, response);

    return response;
  }
  ... 

  @Override
  public Future<byte[]> makeAsyncCall(E env, final String pkg, final String method, byte[] request, ApiConfig apiConfig) {

    examineRequest(pkg, method, request);

    Future<byte[]> innerFuture = baseDelegate.makeAsyncCall(env, pkg, method, request, apiConfig);
    return new HookedFuture<byte[]>(innerFuture) {
      @Override
      protected void futureResultIs(byte[] response) {

        examineResponse(pkg, method, response);

      }
    };

  }
  ... 
}
```

Where the `HookedFuture` class is

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

/**
 * A future that wraps another future, and behaves just like it, except that at the point
 * when the future completes a hook is called.
 *
 * @param <T> the type returned by the future.
 */
public abstract class HookedFuture<T> implements Future<T> {

  private final Future<T> innerFuture;

  /** Make sure hook is only called once */
  private boolean hookCalled = false;

  public HookedFuture(Future<T> future) {
    innerFuture = future;
  }

  /** Client implements this hook, which will be called back on completion of the first
   *   get() */
  protected abstract void futureResultIs(T result);

  @Override
  public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    return innerFuture.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCancelled() {
    return innerFuture.isCancelled();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDone() {
    return innerFuture.isDone();
  }

  @Override
  public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    T result = innerFuture.get(); // may block here
    if (!hookCalled) {
      futureResultIs(result);
      hookCalled = true;
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
      throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    T result = innerFuture.get(timeout, unit); // may block here
    if (!hookCalled) {
      futureResultIs(result);
      hookCalled = true;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```